# iOS app using non-standard cryptography

Tags: ios, encryption, ios9

I'm trying to submit an app to the App Store, but I got stuck with this question

> Does your app implement one or more encryption algorithms that are
>   proprietary or yet to be accepted as standard by international
>   standard bodies (such as, the IEEE, IETF, ITU, and so on)?

The only cryptography the app is using is for the api requests that go over https.

What is the correct answer (Yes/No) in my case?

Answer (score 0):

See https://itunespartner.apple.com/en/apps/faq/Managing%20Your%20Apps_Trade%20Compliance and note that "just using https" would be covered under "An app uses or accesses only encryption algorithms provided in iOS or Mac OS for its security features".

So you would answer No to the specific question you are asking about.